# angular2 slow in IE and usage of core-js

Tags: performance, angular, internet-explorer

I see the angular2 app that I created is much slower (approximately ~5X) in IE11 when compared to other browsers. In IE11, right from the data rendering in a grid, dropdown, pagination are slow whereas the same is super fast and working as expected in other browsers. When I googled, I see using core-js and using enableProdMode() might  improve the performance in IE. I have enabled enableProdMode() but I am not clear how to wireup core-js with the angular2 app. I have included core-js as dependency and installed it. So what would be next step to wireup things.?

Comment: I have included `/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js` as part of the index.html file. Still it badly slow.

Comment: could you please double check, you [followed this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8112#issuecomment-219623759) or not

Comment: @PankajParkar - I did try this before posting the issue in stackoverflow. But unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: did you try ```/node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the following libraries as part of polyfills.ts made my application faster but it never matched the performance to Chrome.

```
import 'core-js/client/core';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'rxjs/bundles/Rx';
import '@angular/core/bundles/core.umd';
import '@angular/common/bundles/common.umd';
import '@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd';
import '@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd';`
```

Beware, adding these files increases the size of the bundle drastically.

Comment: could you tell me, In which component I can add these imports

Answer (score 3):

My issue in angular 6 was an input binding done to a function:

```
<app-my-component [model]="getMyModel()"></app-my-component>
```

I changed that to a variable instead

```
<app-my-component [model]="valueOfGetMyModel"></app-my-component>
```

This simple change fixed a major performance issue for me. Also, the function was using a polyfilled function in IE, while other browsers had native implementation that didn't show any notable issues.

As a final fix, I also changed the changeDetection strategy to onPush as this component has 15 instances in the page.

Answer (score 0):

please create angular project using angularcli commondline

use ng build --prod to compile your angular project

This will work IE same as Chrome. I have tested and working like charm in my application